# Devexpress XtraReport - set query on filterstring

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I have a DexExpress XtraReport and I want to set the filterstring on condition below:
If user didn't select any parameter, report should show data in a month.
If user select driver and lorry No, report should show that driver and lorry at that month.

How should I set the filterstring to get the result above?
[Devexpress XtraReport filterstring screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdcmt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Go through documentation: [XtraReportBase.FilterString Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/xtrareports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReportBase.FilterString.property)

You can Set this property in the following event handlers.

1. The [DataSourceDemanded](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReportBase.DataSourceDemanded.event) event.
2. The [XRControl.BeforePrint](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.BeforePrint.event) event of a report.

> You can also handle the [XRControl.BeforePrint](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.BeforePrint.event) event of a specific
>   report band (e.g., the *DetailBand*). In this event handler, you can
>   access the current data row using the *GetCurrentRow* and
>   *[GetCurrentColumnValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReportBase.GetCurrentColumnValue.method)* methods and cancel printing of the band under a specific condition using the **e.Cancel** property.

Comment: Hi, Niranjan.

I used DataSourceDemanded to customized the sql data source.
However, why is the SqlDataSource return null for the query?

CustomSqlQuery query = this.sqlDataSource1.Queries[1] as CustomSqlQuery;

When i debug, i see the query return null.
I found one article https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T249676/why-is-the-sqldatasource-return-null-for-the-query 

But i have no clue about  the first element of the Queries collection in the latter case doesn't have the CustomSqlQuery type. 
How to make sure to have CustomSqlQuery type?

Comment: Why do you show some code which causing problem. You can either check the type of query in Queries collection or set the filterstring property at BeforePrint event of the report or band which has data source property assigned.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
I solved the problem by put my own sql query in the Query Editor. Now xtraReport can recognize the CustomSqlQuery.
Thanks for your help!